# How to disable Button while AsyncTask is running? (Android)

Tags: android, button, android-asynctask

I am trying to disable a button while a download task is being executed. I have tried using setEnabled, setVisibility and setClickable. I think I tried all combinations of these options. All of them disable the button click events while the task is performing, but the events are still being registered somehow, and when I reactive the button, the handler is called if I clicked the button while it was disabled... even if it was invisible or "gone"! (not sure if it is called a handler, I want to refer to the onClick method).

I have also inserted a counter and a Log to verify what I've stated above. The code is shown below. This piece of code `if(counter>1) return;` is meant to stop the crash, but I would like to remove it, since I want to re-enable the button, and not disable it forever.

**onClick:**

```
public void downloadOnClick(View v) {
    counter++;
    Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), "Button was clicked " + counter + " times.");
    if(counter>1) return;

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        //mButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mButton.setEnabled(false);
        //mButton.setClickable(false);
        mTextView.setText("Getting html file...");
        // if we use simple http, we will need to handle redirect status code
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute("https://www.google.com/");
    } else {
        mTextView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}
```

**AsyncTask:**

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private HttpURLConnection mConnection;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            mConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            mConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            mConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            mConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            mConnection.setDoInput(true);

            mConnection.connect();
            int statusCode = mConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return "Error: Failed getting update notes";
            }

            return readTextFromServer(mConnection);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    private String readTextFromServer(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader stream = null;
        try {
            stream = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(stream);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mTextView.setText(result);
        // Can not reactivate button / cancel (pending?) events....
        //mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mButton.setEnabled(true);
        //mButton.setClickable(true);
    }
}
```

The full project (it is very simple, just a training example) is available to test in this [repository](https://github.com/JSMiranda/android-training/tree/master/Lab4_Ex1) that I have just created.

To conclude, from what I have read, there is in fact a problem regarding button disabling. Mostly this is resolved through the use of a flag to call the onClick method only when the flag is true. Although, this does not solve the problem of re-enabling the button. I have also tried `mButton.cancelPendingInputEvents();` but it does not work (and I do not know why. Click events are not yet registered? Or they are not pending?

Is there a simple solution to this problem? Any ideas? Am I missing some basic detail? If not, I am considering trying to create a new button programatically to contour the problem. If I do not keep references to old buttons, are they deleted through garbage collection?

Thanks in advance!

**[Edit] Clarification:**

Since the title could be misleading in this point, I want to clarify that I am able to disable and re-enable the button and all the functionality is ok **except when the buttion is disabled**. And note that I have added the line `if(counter>1) return;` just to test but it stops the button from working the way I wanted (that's why I am not using a flag. I don't want this line to be there when I solve the problem!). The log is enough to inform me that the method is being called when the button is **re-enabled**, because I clicked it when it was **disabled!**

Comment: SO I don't know what you're seeing, but 6 years of android work tells me that this is absolutely not how setEnabled works-  if the button is disabled it does NOT queue events.  Which leads me to think either you have somethign weird going on in your code or that you're very mistaken.

Comment: I'm running your code, and seeing the exact same behavior.  There are a lot of posts on SO about it, so it seems that it's a known issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DanielNugent . Yep, I think I stated that in my question. But I did not find any ways of re-enabling the button. All questions I found where regarding button disabling, which is what I have already achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that with your example, the `AsyncTask` was completing so fast that there was a very short amount of time that the `Button` was not clickable due to being disabled.  So, it's basically a timing issue.

I found that by delaying the re-enabling of the `Button` by 4 seconds, it works as expected.

Note with this change that visually, the `Button` is re-enabled a split second after the `TextView` is populated.

Here is the code change in `onPostExecute()`:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mTextView.setText(result);

            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //re-enable the button
                    mButton.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }, 4000);
        }
```

Note that you can remove the counter logic and it should work as expected now:

```
public void downloadOnClick(View v) {

    Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), "Button was clicked");

    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

        mButton.setEnabled(false);

        mTextView.setText("Getting html file...");
        // if we use simple http, we will need to handle redirect status code
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute("https://www.google.com/");
    } else {
        mTextView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}
```

Comment: So if I understood this correctly, the problem is that the changes in the UI are being done in a parallel way, and because of that the button is enabled before the TextView is populated. (Even if it seems to be disabled). I assume this because even if I change the order of the graphics changes the button only seems enabled when the text is fully loaded. Adding a breakpoint and debugging, I can see that before the download, the click events are not being listened, but they are when the textView is being populated. Your solutions solves the problem, I'll try to make one more generic from that.

Comment: @JoãoMiranda Yes, it takes time for each `View` to re-draw, so the `Button` was getting re-enabled and accepting click events before it appeared to be re-enabled in the UI.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I don't think I could understand what was going on without your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DOWNLOAD TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="downloadOnClick" />
```

You are missing the concept of **OnClickListener**! First of all, you have to modify the above xml in this way removing onClick attribute:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="DOWNLOAD TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Than you have to modify the Activity onCreate method in order to set the OnClickListener on your button:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            Log.d(this.getLocalClassName(), "Button was clicked " + counter + " times.");
            if(counter>1) return;

            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                mButton.setEnabled(false);
                mTextView.setText("Getting html file...");
                // if we use simple http, we will need to handle redirect status code
                new DownloadWebpageTask().execute("https://www.google.com/");
            } else {
                mTextView.setText("No network connection available.");
            }
         }
     });
}
```

This is the right way to handle a click.

**See more:**

- [Button | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

**Moreover:**

The best way from my point of view is implements the OnClickListener() on your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
}
```

In this way you can write for each button where you need to set the OnClickListener do:

```
buttonX.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonY.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonZ.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In your Activity onClick() you must override the OnClickListener methods, so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonX)){
        //do here what u wanna do.
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonY){
        //do here what u wanna do.
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonZ){
        //do here what u wanna do.
    }
}
```

Also in onClick you could use view.getId() to get the resource ID and then use that in a switch/case block to identify each button and perform the relevant action.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
I thought using xml to point to a method was, in this case (where I don't want to dynamically change what I am calling) the same thing. Anyways, I tried your solution and it still keeps calling the method when I click the disabled button. Notice that the button is still "disabled" (does not perform any action except logging) because I added a conditional return in the beginning of the method! Don't you get the log messages when you click the disabled button? Maybe something weird is happening when I'm testing on my device...

Comment: I never got this problem when disabling a button during an AsyncTask execution. The button is disabled during all the time and no other event is fired if i click on it! I don't know if you are missing something yet! I expect it  works fine.

Comment: It is not working but I will try in the emulator instead of in the phone. If it does not work I will ask more people tomorrow and I will post here if I found the cause of the error. Again, thanks for your time!

Comment: @VoodooCoder  the onClick in the xml dynamically creates the onClickListener for you at compile time, and makes it call the named function on the activity via reflection.  There should be no difference between the two methods, other than trading off a small bit of performance for clarity.

Comment: Can you update the repository with the last changes?

Comment: Done. Although it should behave the same way as before.